# Is there a more readable and efficient way to set up a grid than this in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I recently began learning HTML and CSS and I tried to format my webpage. I ended up with something that is quite unreadable and it seems like there is a better way to do this.

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
body {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(1fr, auto);
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav nav nav" "side1 main1 main1" "side2 main2 main2" "side3 main3 main3" "side4 main4 main4" "footer footer footer"
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

.side1 {
  grid-area: side1;
}

.side2 {
  grid-area: side2;
}

.side3 {
  grid-area: side3;
}

.side4 {
  grid-area: side4;
}

.main1 {
  grid-area: main1;
}

.main2 {
  grid-area: main2;
}

.main3 {
  grid-area: main3;
}

.main4 {
  grid-area: main4;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>CSS Grid Layout</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid-item header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item nav">
      <p>LINK LINK LINK LINK LINK</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item side1">Image goes here</div>

    <div class="grid-item main1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga placeat quaerat dolore soluta distinctio earum totam dolorum reprehenderit nulla. Consectetur, fugiat. Excepturi praesentium molestias odio?</div>

    <div class="grid-item side2">Image goes here</div>

    <div class="grid-item main2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt recusandae iure fugit molestiae earum nesciunt ex accusamus quas distinctio blanditiis!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item side3">Image goes here</div>

    <div class="grid-item main3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quo, ducimus.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item side4">Image goes here</div>

    <div class="grid-item main4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quae magni saepe voluptate repellendus ex modi nam exercitationem quisquam blanditiis. Facere mollitia voluptate, nobis explicabo nam fuga enim eos temporibus ipsum. Deserunt sunt voluptates
        facilis unde, cumque esse commodi quisquam illo dolores accusantium dolor, tenetur ad delectus quam incidunt amet cum maiores corporis quasi repellendus dicta! Aliquam, eum eaque fuga cupiditate dolores molestiae nam dicta, tempora earum dolorum
        id nemo.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item footer">
      <p>My Footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: the webpage]

The image is what it currently looks like. However, I was wondering if there is a more concise way of achieving that.

Comment: What do you mean by "unreadable"?

Comment: @Robo I feel like the written code is a bit messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Semantic markup with reusable styling

Your HTML markup consists entirely of series of `<div />` elements in a big single `grid` container.

I'd suggest you break down into multiple semantic areas (e.g. `<header>`, `<nav>`, `<main>`, etc) and only style the `<main>` as a grid container. In this case, I don't see much benefit of treating the entire layout as one big grid area.

See the code snippet below, which achieves the same layout structure with less lines of code for both HTML and CSS.

```css
body {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

header,
nav,
.grid-item,
footer {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  padding: 10px;
}

header+nav,
nav+main,
main+footer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  LINK LINK LINK LINK
</nav>
<main>
  <div class="grid-item side">Image goes here</div>
  <div class="grid-item main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga placeat quaerat dolore soluta distinctio earum totam dolorum reprehenderit nulla. Consectetur, fugiat. Excepturi praesentium molestias odio?</div>

  <div class="grid-item side">Image goes here</div>
  <div class="grid-item main">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt recusandae iure fugit molestiae earum nesciunt ex accusamus quas distinctio blanditiis!</div>

  <div class="grid-item side">Image goes here</div>
  <div class="grid-item main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quo, ducimus.</div>

  <div class="grid-item side">Image goes here</div>
  <div class="grid-item main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quae magni saepe voluptate repellendus ex modi nam exercitationem quisquam blanditiis. Facere mollitia voluptate, nobis explicabo nam fuga enim eos temporibus ipsum. Deserunt sunt voluptates
    facilis unde, cumque esse commodi quisquam illo dolores accusantium dolor, tenetur ad delectus quam incidunt amet cum maiores corporis quasi repellendus dicta! Aliquam, eum eaque fuga cupiditate dolores molestiae nam dicta, tempora earum dolorum id
    nemo.
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  My Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know there were semantic elements in HTML. Thanks for the help.